# ¿Cómo hacer que una aplicación java ejecute funciones en windows,o bien, escriba texto en aplicaciones de windows?

Tags: java, virtualización

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y me preguntaba si podría hacer alguna aplicación de un teclado en pantalla para windows, no se aún como funcionan los comandos que van al sistema de windows, así que, alguien podría ¿introducirme?,¿recomendarme algún artículo? o si es más simple, decirme de qué manera funcionan ese tipo de comandos?.

Comment: Las preguntas que piden recursos terminan cerradas. Sugiero que investigues. Debe haber diferentes formas de hacerlo. Mediante alguna librería o si lo prefieres, haciendo un dll en C que se encargue de las llamadas al sistema operativo y luego acceder desde Java con JNI.

Answer (score 1):

puede utilizar la clase java.awt.Robot de la biblioteca AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit). La clase Robot permite a una aplicación Java controlar el teclado y el mouse de manera programática.

Por ejemplo, para escribir una cadena de texto en una aplicación de Windows, puede utilizar el siguiente código:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyboardExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    
    // Escribir la cadena "Hello, World!"
    String text = "Hello, World!";
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
      int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
      robot.keyPress(keyCode);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    }
  }
}
```

También puede utilizar la clase Robot para ejecutar funciones de Windows, como simular clicks del mouse o enviar comandos de teclado especiales. Por ejemplo, para simular una combinación de teclas "Ctrl + S" para guardar un archivo, puede utilizar el siguiente código:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyboardExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    
    // Simular la combinación de teclas "Ctrl + S"
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  }
}
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que la clase Robot solo funciona en el entorno de escritorio de Windows y no en otras plataformas como Linux o macOS. Si deseas crear una aplicación de teclado en pantalla para Windows que funcione en diferentes plataformas, puedes utilizar la biblioteca JavaFX para crear una interfaz gráfica de usuario y utilizar la clase javafx.scene.input.Keyboard para controlar el teclado.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me has ayudado mucho, era justo lo que buscaba.